# Deselecting radio buttons while keeping the View Model in synch

Tags: jquery, radio-button, knockout.js

I have a radio group that allows the user (using jQuery events) to deselect previous selections. I am trying to add KnockoutJS to track changes, but the viewmodal gets out of sync with the UI. Can anyone suggest how I might get the two to be in sync?

My view code:

```html
<div id='test'>
    <input data-bind="checked: asd"  name='asd' type='radio' value="a"/>
    <input data-bind="checked: asd"  name='asd' type='radio' value="b"/>
    <input data-bind="checked: asd"  name='asd' type='radio' value="c"/>
</div>
<div>
     <p>Linked Value: <span data-bind="text: asd"></p>  
</div>
```

Corresponding JS:

```
$('#test input[type="radio"]').click(function (event) {
    var checked = $(this).hasClass('checked');
    if (checked) {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
});

var viewModel = {
  asd: ko.observable("a")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

An example can be viewed here online in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VH3K4/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple way would be to do:

```
$('#test input[type="radio"]').click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() === viewModel.asd()) {
         viewModel.asd(null);   
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VH3K4/4/)

Comment: @ RP That works a treat  - many thanks (and for all your helpful posts on Knock Me out)  Ian

Comment: @RP nice, as a side note, trying to get this working via the data-bind="click: ..." method is a total PITA, I couldn't get it working that way.

Comment: @Allen my thought would be to do a custom binding that wraps checked and adds another event handler to null it out on click when equal.  Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/TMZsJ/.  Would need some more work to handle binding against non-observables and could remove jQuery dependency pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the checked attribute, that's done for you.  Change your event to this:

```
$('#test input[type="radio"]').click(function (event) {

    var checked = $(this).hasClass('checked');
    if (checked) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

[Fork of your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/seEUz/)

Comment: thanks for the feedback - however the change means I can no longer deselect the radiogroup which is the intended functionality

Comment: @Ian So you want them to be able to select option a, b, c or neither?  You want this functionality by allowing the user to click on an option 2x, with the second time removing it?

Comment: Yes thats the idea - the user will be able to click on a previously selected value to remove the selection altogether

Comment: @Ian I will look into that, in the mean time, have you considered just adding a "Neither" or "None" sort of option?  That is clearer to the user.

Comment: - thanks - the functionality as described is already in use and I am trying (at least initially) to keep the functionality the same but migrate to use knockoutjs