# Deselecting radio buttons with Knockout while keeping the View Model in synch

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have problem where I am trying to implement a selected/unselected radio buttons.  My radio buttons are dynamically created from the db source.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: attByGroups"

    <-- ko foreach: attributes -->
    <input type="radio" onclick="checkStrenghRadios(this)" data-bind="checked: chkValue, value: 1, attr: { name: 'group' + iAttributeID }"/> 
    <input type="radio" onclick="checkDevRadios(this)" data-bind="checked: chkValue, value: 2, attr: { name: 'group' + iAttributeID }"/>
    <-- /ko -->

</tbody
```

This input radios are inside a knockout foreach loop so it generally creates 2 columns of 30 radio buttons, where I have 2 radios per group.

The foreach loop (attByGroups) source gets created from a computed knockout array, so when try to use a solution to select/unselect a radio button from ([Deselecting radio buttons while keeping the View Model in synch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423253/deselecting-radio-buttons-while-keeping-the-view-model-in-synch/33664320#33664320)), the select/unselect function is called twice, therefore, the radio buttons never gets checked as it is getting checked and unchecked on every click.  I was able to get the radio buttons to select/unselect with another JavaScript function but once the radio is unchecked the viewModel for the radio button was not updated.

my computed function:

```
self.attByGroups = ko.computed(function () {
    var result = [], attGroupId, currentGroup, chkValue;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AttributeList(), function (attObj) {

        chkValue = attObj.iAttributeTypeId;

        if (attObj.iAttributeTypeId == 2)
            ListOfOrigDevRadios.push(attObj.iAttributeID);

        if (attObj.strAttributeGroupID !== attGroupId) {
            attGroupId = attObj.strAttributeGroupID;

            currentGroup = {
                groupHeader: attObj.strAttributeGroup,
                //checkValue: chkValue,
                attributes: []
            }

            result.push(currentGroup);
        }

       attObj.chkValue = ko.observable(chkValue);
       currentGroup.attributes.push(attObj);
    })
    self.ProssRadioBtns();
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Can you share the function definition for checkStrenghRadios and checkDevRadios?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your response.  The checkStrenghRadios and checkDevRadios just basically try to limit number of radio buttons to be 4 out of the potential 30.
checkStrenghRadios = function(input)
         {
             var radios = $('input[type=radio][name^="group"][value="1"]:checked');
             if (radios.length > 4) {
                 alert("you picked too many dude");
                 input.checked = false;
             }
         }

Comment: Btw, the function I am using to select / deselect a radio button is the following:

$.fn.uncheckableRadio = function () {
             return this.each(function () {
                 $(this).mousedown(function () {
                     $(this).data('wasChecked', this.checked);
                     
                 });

                 $(this).click(function () {
                     if ($(this).data('wasChecked'))
                     {
                         this.checked = false;
                     }
                 });
             });
         };

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a hack you can get what you are looking for by not completely using the "checked" binding. By binding to a readonly computed variable you can ensure that you control when the underlying variable is set like below.

```
   //stop writes from checked binding
   attObj.compVal = ko.computed({
        read:function(){
            return attObj.chkValue();
        }
    });
```

mark up

```
 <input type="radio" data-bind="value: 1,checked: compVal, attr: { name: 'group' + iAttributeID },click:toggle"/>
```

the checked binding would only be able to read not assign to "chkValue". then the code below would take care of determining the "chkValue" and decide what happens when the radiobutton is unselected.

```
//handle updateing the viewModel on click
        attObj.toggle=function(vm,e){
            //if the value of the element is same as the value of the binding
            //change the checked value to 0 to unselect
            if($(e.srcElement).val()==attObj.chkValue())
                attObj.chkValue(0);
            else
                attObj.chkValue($(e.srcElement).val());

            return true;
        };
```

I have created a jsfiddle to demo my solution https://jsfiddle.net/he80g8xg/6/ , I hope this sheds some light to your problem.

Comment: Sam, that worked like a champ, I am still new to knockout so this was a good lesson learned.  Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and providing a solution.

Comment: Sam, I thought I had it working, but it is still not 100% working so I was wondering if you could assist me.  Your solution works great to update the chkValue however, my radio buttons are not being marketed selected when I click on it.  I added another function to do select /unselected radio buttons and still doesn't work:

Comment: What's happening is that when I click on the radio button this function to select or unselect a radio button is called twice every time which selects the radio button on the first call and unselects the radio button on the second call.  Any thoughts why this function is being called twice when a radio button is clicked?

Comment: Never mind i got it to work the way I want it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rmello/z6qh26tL/ , I think somewhere else in my project code is making that select/unselect function to be called twice, hence not making the radio button checked after clicking it once

Comment: The issue I was having was using knockout library 3.4.0 with jqwidgets, I change to knockout library 3.0.0 and now it works.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't much help ... but looks like you got it figured out eventually :)